# cocos multi touch game

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing some games using multi touch for iPhone (cocos). Could anyone teach me how to start, from very scratch beginning. I am not sure where to start or any resources that can help. I really appreciate the helps.

```
@implementation GameScene

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        Sprite *background = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"unzip.png"];

        background.position = CGPointMake(240,160);
        [self addChild:background];

        Label *aboutContent = [Label labelWithString:@"Welcome to the game" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:30];
        aboutContent.position = CGPointMake(240,160);
        [self addChild:aboutContent];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I have this code. This import the image . The just want the players can touch 2 points A and B in the centre and move them in the opposite sides far from each other. Could anyone give me some examples.?

Answer (score 2):

Monocle Studios has [a whitepaper: introduction to cocos2d iphone](http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html).
Pretty good place to start from.

Touches can be detected by any Layer by settings `isTouchEnabled` property to YES.

Any other `CocosNode` class descendant can implement the protocol `TargetedTouchDelegate` and `StandardTouchDelegate` and then register itself with the touch dispatcher:

```
[[TouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self
                                    priority: 0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

You must then implement:

- `- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
- `- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
- `- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

in that object.

Hope that helps.